# setting advanced parameters for Jdbc.getConnection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to connect securely to **SQL Google Cloud Platform** using **Google Apps Script**.  However, I'm not sure how to set the parameters `_serverSslCertificate, _clientSslCertificate`, and `clientSslKey` of `Jdbc.getConnection` method.  I already downloaded cert and key files.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAlj6vYtt6F8rv254sllmvGogSYwzS0JaB6Yezji6Ab+gmZPLc
dyfNIg4PTe8YCz45RnJ+8VVklTQ4K/MFzsB6nilNMDSFRCAfRmytQkioEFlgzdL+
...
JOyb/68aCqHHStwlpCUTH40Iqh3kneiQ1be2XigxjllMSYkuH/ebZw==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How should I assign a string literal to `_serverSslCertificate`?  For example...

```
var serverSslCert = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAlj6vYtt6F8rv254sllmvGogSYwzS0JaB6Yezji6Ab+gmZPLc\n\
dyfNIg4PTe8YCz45RnJ+8VVklTQ4K/MFzsB6nilNMDSFRCAfRmytQkioEFlgzdL+\n\
...
JOyb/68aCqHHStwlpCUTH40Iqh3kneiQ1be2XigxjllMSYkuH/ebZw==\n\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';
```

Answer (score 3):

The certs are send in the info parameter of getConnection(url,info).
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getconnectionurl-info

Example:

```
var serverSslCert = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("serverSslCert");

 var sqlInfo = {_serverSslCertificate: serverSslCert,
                _clientSslCertificate:"...",
                _clientSslKey:"..."
               };

 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://yoursqlserver.example.com:3306/database_name',
                                sqlInfo);
```

There are some Google Cloud SQL specific connection methods in the JDBC service though.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getcloudsqlconnectionurl-info

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getconnectionurl-username-password

Comment: How should I assign a string literal to `_serverSslCertificate`?   Please see the edited question.

Comment: Paste the keys/certs into the script properties and fetch them with the PropertiesService. You will not have to worry about formatting and they stay out of your code.