# Securely allow Google App Engine to internal company network/servers for Google Apps Scripts

Tags: security, google-apps-script, firewall, network-security

It is well documented that Google Apps Script run on Google App Engine servers that  would not have access to a company's internal network/server:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#using_jdbcgetconnectionurl

Per the documentation, if you want a Google Apps Script project to have access to an internal network/server then you will have to white-list Google's IPs. But we all know that isn't the safest option. In fact, the documentation even says so:

> Note that using static IP address filtering is not considered a safe and effective means of protection. For example, an attacker could set up a malicious App Engine app which could share the same IP address range as your application. Instead, we suggest that you take a [defense in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)) approach using [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oauth) and [Certs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_certificates).

The issue is I cannot find any documentation, reference material, or articles on how best an organization should do what it suggests.

So my question is, how can an organization using G-Suite Enterprise securely allow Google Apps Script projects to access the company's internal network?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation made it quite clear, that since App Scripts are ran on shared App Engine instances, it is impossible to restrict with IP, and that also implies the networking capability would be very limited (i.e. no VPC peering or alike). Therefore, as in the highlighted block, they suggest implementing authentication over just IP restriction.

Apart from authentication, App Script also supports [encrypting and authenticating the server with SSL](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getConnection(String,Object)) ([sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891556/setting-advanced-parameters-for-jdbc-getconnection)). This should protect the connection from being eavesdropped when sent over the Internet.

Further more, you can implement a "semi IP restriction" mechanism, technically called [Port Knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking), which briefly works as follow:

1. First create a special endpoint, requires authentication, accepts an IP address as input. When requested, you open up your firewall to accept connection from that IP to your internal network *for a limited time* (e.g. 5min).
2. In your App Script, use URL Fetch to request that endpoint, so that your scripts instance is temporarily allowed to access your network.

Of course that will not be perfect, since one App Engine instance runs many scripts concurrently and the whitelist is opened for a set time, but still this is considerably better than persistently opening the port to all Google (App Engine) IPs.

Comment: The encrypting and authentication link is for connecting to a database. We don't want to connect to a DB. We want to make an API call to an internal server. And I know the port knocking system would work but its still not secure. I am surprised Google doesn't have an official way to support this.

Answer (score 1):

Apps Script is a great tool for simplifying tasks when you are using ***G Suite services***, unfortunately, what you are trying to achieve is not available. Also, keep in mind Apps Script is **not** built on App Engine, it's a completely different product.

Therefore if what it is shown in the documentation can't fulfill the requirements you have, please check other Google alternatives like [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/)  or [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/gcp/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=emea-es-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-gcp-1007176&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_167371270453-ADGP_Hybrid+%7C+AW+SEM+%7C+BKWS+~+EXA_1:1_ES_EN_General_Cloud_TOP_google+cloud+platform-KWID_43700016297094581-kwd-26415313501-userloc_1005424&utm_term=KW_google%20cloud%20platform-ST_google+cloud+platform&ds_rl=1242853&ds_rl=1245734&ds_rl=1245734&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5tCBw_LS5QIVFoXVCh0IoQ_mEAAYASAAEgKixvD_BwE), instead of [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en_ie/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=emea-es-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-t1-1007172&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_264253570922-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20~%20EXA_1:1_ES_EN_G%20Suite_GSB01_g%20suite-KWID_43700032115353219-kwd-7564271891-userloc_1005424&utm_term=KW_g%20suite-g&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzLujj_PS5QIVWPlRCh3JHgG1EAAYASAAEgKgcvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).