# Google App Script (not) using GCP Classic VPN route?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

This reads like a duplicate of other GAS+VPN/SDC questions but none of the existing questions refer explicitly to using a GCP Hybrid (Classic) VPN to provide App Script access to on-premise resources.

I have the GCP VPN setup and working (verified pinging both ways via VM) and I have associated the App Script project with the GCP resource but the App Script cannot URLFetch from anywhere over the VPN. Is this a known limitation of App Script or can someone point me in the right direction please?

edit 1: I have also tried to setup a Serverless VPC Connector but as App Script has no VM instance, I couldn't complete the Connector setup. Giving network.user access to the App Script's GCP service accounts didn't achieve anything.

edit 2:
[@eric-wong wrote the following in an answer to a smiliar question 2 years ago:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58593472/securely-allow-google-app-engine-to-internal-company-network-servers-for-google)

> The documentation made it quite clear, that since App Scripts are ran on shared App Engine instances, it is impossible to restrict with IP, and that also implies the networking capability would be very limited (i.e. no VPC peering or alike)

I cannot understand why Google would provide the ability to link an App Script to a GCP project but then not provide a mechanism to utilise the GCP's network.

I originally [asked this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1054871/google-app-script-not-using-routing-over-classic-vpn-to-onsite-server) as I thought I had a GCP config issue but now I'm feeling like it's more like a GAS issue.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: What type of Apps Script project is this? I don't really know how I could reproduce your environment to test this out. What have you researched from Apps Script limits that makes you think you might be hitting one?

Comment: Maybe this helps you? https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules

Comment: @Aerials the Firewall is not the issue. I had previously created ingress/egress rules to the VPN network and I can see that these rules are not being hit at all.

At it's core the App Script project is a GSheet performing a `URLFetchApp.fetch("https://<IP on VPN subnet>", { 'validateHttpsCertificates' : false } )` which throws an Exception of "Exception: Bad request: https://<IP on VPN>".

Comment: I have read through pages of Apps Script and GCP Network documentation but haven't read anything concrete on App Script having (or not) access to a GCP VPN resource. 

This is making me think it's unsupported but I'd like someone, somewhere, to confirm?

Comment: does an App Script run locally? Do you get anything if you chuck https://<IP on VPN subnet> in a browser on the same machine?

Comment: Apps Script will always run in Google servers.

Comment: @Aerials "Apps Script will always run in Google servers" is absolutely correct.

This is why I am trying to utilise a GCP VPN to attach to onsite resources.

Comment: I think the solution is going to end up being a contrived architecture of App Script to GCP VM\App Engine App -> VPC -> VPN -> Onsite. At which point we'd might as well just invest in developing a public facing API and removing the requirement for the GCP components.